# Mac , arduino nao reconhece a porta imusb

Tags: arduino, mac

Comprei um arduino UNO ( acredito que não é o original ) , baixei a IDE , instalei normal , conectei a placa ( acendeu normalmente , fui na IDE em ferramentas > placas e selecionei Arduino/genuíno UNO , fui em ferramentas > portas  era para selecionar usb , porem não tem essa opção , apenas    bluetooth ... O que posso fazer para poder reconhecer e poder programar ? 
Lembrando que estou com macbook pro , e mac os x ultima versão ... 
Obrigado 
[image: foto do arduino]

Comment: Veja se [isso](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12133/mac-osx-yosemite-no-serial-ports-showing-for-uno-r3) te ajuda. Eu uso Linux, mas estou pesquisando sobre o problema para poder te ajudar.

Comment: Sabe reconhecer se o conversor serial é um chip atmega8 ou um FTDI? Se for um FTDI, provavelmente precisarás instalar o [driver FTDI](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/mac). Se não souber identificar, por favor, tire uma foto (com uma boa qualidade) do chip próximo ao conector USB fêmea (padrão B) do seu Arduino. Mas é muito simples, basta ler se há um identificador como "atmega8" ou "FTDI".

Comment: @Avelino n consegui achar ... Vou postar a foto

Comment: Tudo bem. Estou voltando para casa agora, ficarei aproximadamente 1h offline. Mas acho que os links que deixei podem te ajudar.

Comment: Estou pelo smartphone. Consegue ler algo no chip próximo ao cristal oscilador e o conector USB? Se parece muito com um FTDI, mas só posso ter certeza se estiver realmente escrito. Tenta instalar o driver, tem as instruções no link dos meus primeiros comentários.

Comment: Procurei, porem n achei .... Fiquei procurando ....

Comment: A propósito, isto não se parece com uma placa Arduino Original. Mas não há problema, o hardware ė o mesmo.

Comment: Não é original msm .... Amigo essa classificação chama como ? Pois assim posso pesquisar algum local onde esra escrito ...

Comment: [Aqui](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/mac) tem mais um tutorial. Bem, como Arduino possui hardware livre, qualquer um pode montar uma placa e vender. Só não se pode usar o nome "Arduino", pois ė uma marca registrada. Ė claro que os chineses não ligam para isto. Agora, isto não tem importância, o hardware ė idêntico ou muito similar ao original.

Comment: Mas o meu é ftd ? Pois não queria instalar um drive desnecessariamente ...

Comment: Amigo instalei o driver como indica o tutorial e nada....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre os vários modelos e clones de Arduino, alguns oferecem adaptador USB/serial que é reconhecido automaticamente pelo Mac, outros exigem uma instalação de driver bem simples, e outros ainda exigem uma instalação de driver um pouco trabalhosa. Este artigo apresenta os passos dessas instalações de drivers: http://br-arduino.org/2015/11/arduino-ch340-mac.html